# How can I create abstract method to create BehaviorRelay in Swift?

Tags: abstract, rx-swift

I want to create an abstract method which can return an Observable or Relay.

It gives me below error i.e. `use of undeclared type 'type'`

[image]

Comment: The `BehaviorRelay` init is already generic and an abstract method would be in a protocol, not a class. What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can see there is a function called `createObservables()`, I want to create many variables in there using the `createBehaviourRelay` method that I am trying to define. I don't want to use everytime the word `BehaviourRelay`

Comment: And even I was planning to inherit this class and create required `BehavorRelays` in the base class using method `createBehaviorRelay` by passing the type and value.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the word `BehaviorRelay`? Why do you think that `createBehaviorRelay(Bool.self, value: false)` is better to write than `BehaviorRelay(value: false)`?